# htaccess redirection when URL has ? query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

From URL with pattern-

> http://example.com/top-100-selenium-interview-questions-answers.html?format=pdf

I want to redirect to

> http:// example.com/istqb_dump.pdf

I have created redirect following rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule .* http:// example.com/istqb_dump.pdf? [R=301,L]
```

It was working fine.

Now there are other URL as well like below -

> http://example.com/top-35-seo-interview-questions/?format=pdf
>
> http://examplecom/top-15-digital-marketing-interview-questions/?format=pdf

That I want to redirect to respective URL live

> http:// example.com/seo.pdf
>
> http:// example.com/digital-marketing.pdf

But with above rule, all URL are redirect to

> http:// example.com/istqb_dump.pdf

How can I configure induvial redirection?

Comment: Be more specific with what you let your RewriteRule match …?

Comment: I want to redirecte From url - 
http://example.com/top-100-selenium-interview-questions-answers.html?format=pdf
to this url
http://example.com/istqb_dump.pdf 
please tell me the .htaccess rule.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make you `RewriteRule` more specific, creating a bespoke condition for each case:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^top-100-selenium-interview-questions-answers.html /istqb_dump.pdf? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^top-35-seo-interview-questions/? /seo.pdf? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^top-15-digital-marketing-interview-questions/? /digital-marketing.pdf? [R=301,L]
```

Demo here: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=97bf4828-2ec0-551e-8bc1-4fb9f2f0f278